# An ordinary generating function involving the gamma function

Tags: analysis, generating-functions, gamma-function

Is there anything known about ordinary generating functions of the form
$$
S(z;a) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Gamma(ani)z^n,
$$
for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $a \neq 0$. Here $i$ is the imaginary unit. Is there a nice expression for it, or good bounds, in terms of $z,a$? Thanks.

**Edit 1:** An application of the root test and the fact that $|\Gamma(\sigma + it)| \sim \sqrt{2\pi}|t|^{\sigma - 1/2}e^{-\pi |t|/2}$ as $|t| \to \infty$, for $\sigma$ fixed (see for instance Corollary 16 [here](https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/_media/ma3001/2014v/analytisktallteori/the_riemann_zeta_function_notes.pdf)) shows that $S(z;a)$ has radius of convergence $e^{\pi|a|/2}$.

**Edit 2:** I have also posted this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270159/an-ordinary-generating-function-involving-the-gamma-function)

Comment: Do you know when this converges?

Comment: I added info about this. See the edit.

Comment: You could always try on MathOverflow if you don't get a good answer here.

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a try. Let's see.

Comment: It's generally preferred to put links in both posts to the other when cross-posting.  Otherwise someone might put a lot of work into an answer to one only to find it's already been answered in the other.

Comment: Good idea. Done.